# Install Windows 7 on Mac from USB

Tags: windows-7, mac, usb, boot-camp

Is it possible to install Windows 7 on Mac from a USB stick, using Boot Camp? (it's so much faster than the usual CD/DVD install)

And the second question is: during the installation process (as described here: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3986) I have to insert the SN install DVD. The problem is that I only have .dmg, so my question is: can I just use that instead of the DVD?

Answer (score 1):

With the advent of Macs that have no optical drive, there's more information on this now:

http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-20020513-285/install-win-7-on-macbook-air-from-a-usb-drive/

Answer (score -1):

Here are [two](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-install-windows-7vista-from-usb-drive-detailed-100-working-guide/) [guides](http://www.maximumpc.com/article/howtos/how_to_install_windows_7_beta_a_usb_key) on installing Win7 onto a USB.

As for your bootcamp problem I'm not to sure on that.

What you could do is try and install on a [VM](http://virtualbox.org) first. Then from there install Windows7 onto USB and then use that instead of a CD or .ding file.

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for. I need to install it from USB on a Mac, via Boot Camp.